# Migrate composite-component to custom-component

Tags: java, jsf-2, facelets, composite-component

I have to migrate a composite-component to a custom-component. This example is rather simplified, but demonstrates the problem: the childs of my component (`my:test`) need to be rendered in another component. The composite `my:testC`, as an example which I don't want to use, would look like this

```
<composite:implementation>
  <p:panel>
    <composite:insertChildren/>
  </p:panel>
</composite:implementation>
```

Obviously (at least I hope I'm correct with this assumption) I can not simply render the `p:panel` in `encodeBegin`.

```
@FacesComponent("test")
public class Test extends UIPanel
{   
  @Override
  public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException
  {
    // ??
  }

  @Override
  public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context) throws IOException
  {
   // ??
  }
}
```

I want to use `my:test` in a way like this:

```
<my:test>
  <h:outputText value="some Text"/>
</my:test>
```

The output should be the same than using `my:testC`: *some Text* rendered in a PrimeFaces panel. How can I encode the usage of `p:panel` in my Java class?

Comment: I do not understand the concrete problem/question (in fact, there's nowhere a concrete question). Are you concretely asking how to encode the same output of `<p:panel>` in your custom component?  Or are you concretely asking how to reuse the default encoder (renderer) of `<p:panel>` for that part? The children is not the problem at all as `encodeChildren()` does it all automatically, howerver the last sentence of the first paragraph seems to indicate otherwise, which is confusing.

Comment: @BalusC Thank you for looking in this issue. I have updated the question, hopefully it is better to understand now. To answer your question: I'm trying to encode the same output of `p:panel`.

Answer (score 0):

You observed that correctly. You cannot simply render "p:panel" or any other jsf markup in a custom component.

What you can do however:

- Instantiate the subcomponents using the Application instance, add it as a facet or child to your custom component and then call encode on it in your own renderer.
- Directly render HTML
- Use the facelet API that should be available in the current JSF (I have never actually worked with that)
- Use any other template processing like velocity or freemarker to render HTML.